# HEROKU : deploy a symfony 4 app push failed

Tags: heroku, symfony4

```
josh@josh:~/my_projects/la_manne$ git push heroku master
Énumération des objets: 3, fait.
Décompte des objets: 100% (3/3), fait.
Écriture des objets: 100% (3/3), 230 octets | 230.00 Kio/s, fait.
Total 3 (delta 0), réutilisés 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:             HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 73ed9a909f2a7e80a0a45f0f5d86aa6c7fdd70c1
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 73ed9a909f2a7e80a0a45f0f5d86aa6c7fdd70c1
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to lamanne.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/lamanne.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: impossible de pousser des références vers 'https://git.heroku.com/lamanne.git'
```

Comment: Can you provide your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:             HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
```

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php#usage

> You'll need to use at least an empty `composer.json` in your
> application.
>
> ```
> $ echo '{}' > composer.json
> $ git add composer.json
> $ git commit -m "add composer.json for PHP app detection"
> ```
>
> If you also have files from other frameworks or languages that could
> trigger another buildpack to detect your application as one of its
> own, e.g. a `package.json` which might cause your code to be detected
> as a Node.js application even if it is a PHP application, then you
> need to manually set your application to use this buildpack:
>
> ```
> $ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
> ```
>
> This will use the officially published version. To use the default
> branch from GitHub instead:
>
> ```
> $ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
> ```
>
> Please refer to Dev Center for further usage instructions.